# Excel List of Blank Cells

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a big excel sheet with a bunch of empty cells in various locations. I want an easy to work with list of which cells are empty. I was hoping to make a new worksheet that was populated with the locations of the empty cells. I wanted to have this to just populate the cells I want it to. I kept the header from the worksheet I will be checking and added a blank cells count, so I want the following cells in the column to be populated by the list of empty cell locations.

Now I know I can use [`=ISBLANK`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) to test if a cell is empty or not, but I only care about the cells that return `TRUE`. So I figure I'll need a [loop](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html). And I want the location of the cell so I can use [`=CELL`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf). And to make this most readable I want to do this on a column by column basis.

But I want to populate a spreadsheet with this information in a manner similar to how functions work (I just want to copy and paste it to other cells and columns). But it's [pretty clear that I am going to need VBA](https://www.quora.com/What-the-difference-between-using-Excel-worksheet-formulas-and-macros).

My question is how can I create a macro to populate my spreadsheet with a list of empty cells? How do I apply it to the cells?

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to populate a workbook with a list of empty cells ...? Do you mean you want to show the Cell Address of those empty cells? I.e. if `A1` and `A4`, and `A6` are empty, you want a new workbook that shows `A1`, `A4`, etc.?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, sorry. I'll edit the post to try and make that more clear. Awesome handle by the way.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have data in sheet1, I have used sample range// Range("A1:c15") however you can define range as per need and blank cells address will be published in next sheet.

```
Sub FindBlank()
Dim rng As Range
dim i as long

For Each rng In Sheet1.Range("A1:c15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
i = i + 1
Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = rng.Address

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of the cells that are empty, you can use `Range().SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlank)`:

```
Sub getEmptyCellAddresses()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' CHANGE AS NECESSARY
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) ' Edit/change range as necessary
ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = rng.Cells.Address ' Change `ws.cells(1, 2)` to whatever destination you like
End Sub
```

Edit: Ah, beaten by 16 seconds by @RamAnuragi ...but anyways, they're slightly different ways to tackle the question so I'll leave it.

Edit: For funsies, here's another way to put them all in a column, one row per cell...and more, per your comments.

```
Sub listEmptyCells()
Dim emptyAddresses() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' CHANGE AS NECESSARY
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A15")

If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("No empty cells in the range")
    Exit Sub
End If

emptyAddresses() = Split(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address, ",")

For i = LBound(emptyAddresses) To UBound(emptyAddresses)
    ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = emptyAddresses(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: How do I get the first one to work? Where do I run it?

Comment: @CGTheLegend - You would add it to a workbook module. See [this page](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html) for how to do that.

Comment: Yes I know how to do that, It's just when I run it nothing happens. I must be using the wrong range or something. How do I specify which sheet? I tried using a method similar to what @RamAnuragi used but it's giving me object errors.

Comment: @CGTheLegend - Check my edit. I added a `Worksheet` variable. Change the worksheet name as necessary. That should do it for you.  Note that `Sheet1` isn't *necessarily* the same as `Sheets("Sheet1")`.

Comment: Ok, so it works but not exactly how I want to. I want it to populate the each cell with one entry, not just give me the whole list in one cell. How do I go about that?

Comment: Also, is there a way to not get an error if no results are found?

Comment: And how do make this more modular so that I can have it fill up multiple columns?

Comment: @CGTheLegend - The second code will put one address in a cell, starting in `B2`, and going down the column. I'll edit it to show a message, if no empty cells are found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143335/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-cgthelegend).