# Retrieve list of headers of blank cells in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to retrieve a list of headers where their succeeding row is blank/ empty. **Is this possible without having to use VBA?**

VBA solution I found: [Excel List of Blank Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767296/excel-list-of-blank-cells)

Below is my sample data and desired output.

[image]

I've worked with this formula but it displayed an incorrect output:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1;SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$C$4="")*(COLUMN($A$2:$C$4))))-COLUMN($A$1))
```

I am guessing I need to use index and match then store all months with blank cells in them in an array.

Comment: Which version of excel do you have? Excel365 with dynamic formulas will be easier to achieve your desired result. Filter() with MMULT() will work.

Answer (score 0):

This array formula may work:

```
=TRIM(CONCAT(IF(ISBLANK(A2:C2),$A$1:$C$1,"")&" "))
```

(array formulas are entered using **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of regular **Enter**)

[image]

---

If comas are needed enclose the formula with `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCAT(IF(ISBLANK(A2:C2),$A$1:$C$1,"")&" "))," ",", ")
```

[image]

---

This array formula also works if you use Excel 2019:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(ISBLANK(A2:C2),$A$1:$C$1,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried the formula but it did not work. For the first row, it only displayed blank. The second row returned "January" only... am I missing anything?

Comment: 1. Which is the cell that contains "January" in your sheet? 2. Which of the three formulas have you tried?

Comment: Oh, apologies. A = January, B = February, C = March

Comment: Still I am not sure what is wrong. You should be as precise as possible. I don't know which formula you used, which cell (e.g. A1) is your January put in. A couple of things to think about: if January is in A1, you should put your formula in row 2, e.g. cell E2; also, make sure you use Ctrl+Shift+Enter (this way you will get those curly braces around the formula, these curly braces would not work if you typed them manually).

Comment: Another thing. Maybe your blank values are not actually blank. You said that second data row returned only January (while March was also expected). You should check if C3 is blank. You can use formula `=ISBLANK(C3)`. It will return `TRUE` only if C3 is really blank. If it returns `FALSE`, it would mean that even if you do not see anything in C3, something still is there, so formulas will not accept is as blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind spaces and the absence of commas then this formula works:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),$A$1,"")&" "&IF(ISBLANK(B2),$B$1,"")&" "&IF(ISBLANK(C2),$C$1,"")
```